# How can I change the headers of an uploaded CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, backend, fastapi

I have an application with Python and FastAPI which has an endpoint that receives a CSV file from the client to later save its content in a non-relational database (so I convert the CSV to dictionary). However I want to edit the CSV header to save it with a different one in the database.
I tried the following:

```
import csv

keynames = [
    'operator',
    'department',
    'city',
    'locality',
    'neighborhood',
    'start_date',
    'final_date',
    'reason',
    'description'
]

def convert_csv(upload_file):
    'Converts a csv to a list of dictionaries'
    with upload_file.file as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile.read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(), fieldnames=keynames)
        reader.__next__()
        data = []
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    return data
```

I thought it had worked, but the data was messed up! (For example the content of "operator" in "start_date" and more errors).
What is going on?

Comment: If the values are in the wrong columns, the header layout doesn't match the column layout (i.e. `operator` isn't the first column). The sequence has to be identical.

Comment: I can't believe it. I've been trying to fix it for hours and as you say, it was a problem of having the new columns defined correctly. I hadn't put the last two in "keynames" which made everything move. Thank you so much!